# IE6 showing wrong background image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, yui

Im using the YUI tabs components and customised each tab to show a unique icon and then show a variation of the icon when the tab is selected.

As we know YUI adds 'selected' class to the selected tab and I manually added 'nav-xxx' where xxx is the tab name  to each tab.

Im using the following css:

```
.nav-directory {
    background: url(/images/nav-browse.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:34px;
    width:141px;
}

.nav-directory.selected {
    background: url(/images/nav-browse-selected.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.nav-admin{
    background: url(/images/nav-admin.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:34px;
    width:121px;
}

.nav-admin.selected {
    background: url(/images/nav-admin-selected.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

This works perfectly in all browsers including IE8 but not IE6. When a tab is selected it shows the same 'selected' background, nomatter which tab is selected.

Doesn't IE6 support combined classes correctly??

I know its hard to explain without showing the page but its on a intranet system.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ie6 doesn't understand chained class names, ie ".nav-admin.selected" won't work in ie.

It will just look at the last class name and ignore the rest.

Comment: Ah thanks alot, thought so. Before I used to think whats the deal with the fuss about IE6. Now Im starting to see how much utter trash it really is!

Comment: One possible workaround is using spriting--putting both the selected and non-selected images in one png, so that the .selected class only changes the background-position and not the whole png.

Comment: Yeah nice one, got it sorted. Thanks!

Comment: Thats wrong! IE6 understand until 3 classes: .class.class2.class3, not beyond that. However, it doesn't understand if its an ID in some (well, most) case, like so: #id.class

Comment: IE6 does not understand 2 classes. See: http://www.oppenheim.com.au/2009/05/24/multiple-css-classes-a-little-known-ie6-hack/